# Python for loop multi-dimensional array indexing issue

Tags: python, arrays, loops

I have the first two strings in a string list `strs` that is guaranteed to have length of at least 2. I want to compare their letters against each other, and perform a task when their letters are identical. Here is the code I am using:

```
        iter_len = len(strs[1])
        if (len(strs[0]) >= len(strs[1])):
            iter_len = len(strs[0])
        
        for i in range (0, iter_len, 1):
            if (strs[0][i] == strs[1][i]):
                [do a thing]
```

However, when I run this, I get a `IndexError: string index out of range` for the `if (strs[0][i] == strs[1][i]):` line. I don't quite understand why this is happening, as the first `if` statement should ensure that `iter_len` is the minimum length between `strs[0]` and `strs[1]`, and should prevent the index from going over. Any advice is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to iterate through two sequences in lockstep, it's generally best practice to use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
for a,b in zip(strs[0], strs[1]):
    if a == b:
        #[do a thing]
```

This will deal with the issue of one sequence being longer than the other.

If you need the index, you can use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#enumerate) with your `zip`:

```
for i, (a, b) in enumerate(zip(strs[0], strs[1])):
    if a == b:
        #[do a thing with i]
```